# How do I overload a function with union type instances

Tags: typescript, redux, overloading

I have this payload type

```
type DriverReducerPayloadType = User | Direction | moment.Moment | boolean
```

This action type

```
type DriverReducerActionType =
  | 'SET_DIRECTION'
  | 'SET_CURRENT_USER'
  | 'SET_IS_LOADING'
  | 'SET_SELECTED_DATE'
```

This action interface

```
interface IDriverReducerAction {
  type: DriverReducerActionType
  payload: { data: DriverReducerPayloadType }
}
```

And this action creator function.

```
export function driverReducerAction(
  type: DriverReducerActionType,
  payload: DriverReducerPayloadType
): IDriverReducerAction {
  return { type, payload: { data: payload } }
```

I want to lock action types to payload types so that `SET_DIRECTION` accepts only a `Direction` type as payload, etc.
How do I properly overload this? If I just write the overloads with the literals from the action type, it seems to lose its point of writing the type out. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do it without literals.
Here is how I would do it:

```
type Overload<T, P> = (type: T, payload: P) => { type: T; payload: { data: P } };

type DriverReducerActionFunc =
  & Overload<'SET_DIRECTION', Direction>
  & Overload<'SET_CURRENT_USER', User>
  & Overload<'SET_IS_LOADING', boolean>
  & Overload<'SET_SELECTED_DATE', moment.Moment>;

export const driverReducerAction: DriverReducerActionFunc = (type, payload) => {
  return { type, payload: { data: payload } };
};
```

If `noImplicitAny` is set to `true`:

```
export const driverReducerAction = <DriverReducerActionFunc>((type, payload) => {
  return { type, payload: { data: payload } };
});
```

Comment: getting a "X is not assignable to Y" error that's too long to post as a comment here

Comment: @dili021 I guess, you have `noImplicitAny` compiler option enabled, right?

Comment: Also, now that it's defined as a function, it's complaining inside the reducer when trying to access `action.type` etc.

Comment: I don't want to use any, that's the whole point.

Comment: Made it work for `noImplicitAny`. Updated the answer

Comment: The `noImplicitAny` solution isn't right. <DriverReducerFunc> doesn't go there. Also, with the previous solution `useReducer`'s `dispatch` is now complaining with `expected 0 arguments, but got 1`